# Field collection table print row number

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'd like to print a row number at the start of each table row in a field collection table.

Is this possible? Could you please explain?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field table collection module is kind enough to provide a specific theme function for tables that it outputs.

As such, you can implement a preprocess hook for the `theme_table__field_collection_table()` function and add your row numbers in there:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_table__field_collection_table(&$vars) {
  // Add a new (blank) header
  array_unshift($vars['header'], '&nbsp;');

  // Add an incremental count to each row
  $count = 1;
  foreach ($vars['rows'] as $key => &$row) {
    array_unshift($row['data'], $count++);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are the best man!

Comment: Not sure about that ;) I've updated the code, I think there was a slight error that would have annihilated the first column of your table...the new code should work fine

Comment: you were right works just fine now. Still… you're the best.